# Logging test results in dashboard when running locally with test runner

Tags: cypress

We have our cypress tests completely separate from the code of the application, because we are not the developers but QA engineers and we also don't have access to the source code of the application.

So we run our cypress tests locally with test runner. Is it then still possible to log the results in the cypress dashboard, or is this only possible with CI?

If it is only possible with CI, because our tests are in a github repository, is it then possible to add CI to the tests where we manually trigger the CI to run the tests on the application? Or is this only possible when the tests are inside the application repository?

Comment: You can publish your results to Dashboard while running your tests locally. You just have to make changes to `cypress.json` file. If that works, I can explain how?

Comment: It would be great if you can explain how to do that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For configuring Cypress Dashboard, you can do like this:

Step 1: Open the Test runner and Go to ‘Runs’.

[image]

Step 2: Click on ‘Connect to Dashboard’ and login using either Github, Google or SSO Account.

[image]

Step 3: Next Step is to set up the project. It comes with pre-filled details, but if you want to change them, you can. Make sure you change the option for Who should see the runs and recordings? to private if you don’t want your test runs to be publicly available. And then finally click on the ‘Set up project’ button.

[image]

Step 4: Once you set up your project to record, cypress generates a unique projectId for your project and automatically inserts it into your `cypress.json` file. This helps cypress uniquely identify your project. The record key is used to authenticate that your project is allowed to record tests to the Dashboard Service. As long as your record key stays private, nobody will be able to record test runs for your project – even if they have your projectId.

```
{
   "projectId":"d5zibb"
}
```

[image]

Step 5: Next step is to run the tests using your record key:

```
npx cypress run --record --key 1nsadk-j938nk-84814-jasdjk
```

Step 6: Now go to the [Cypress Dashboard](https://dashboard.cypress.io/login) and check your test run.

[image]

One thing to take care is that Cypress Dashboard is a paid service but has a free tier as well:

[image]